# How to connect firebase-auth to firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

A have got a project in react-native with rest api auntification in firebase like:

```
 const hanldeLogin = () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword',
      params: {
        key: '....',
      },
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      }
    }).then(res => {
      setUser(res.data)
    })
    .catch(e => {})
    .finally(() => {
      setIsLoading(false)
    })
```

I need to connect my users data like token to firebase real time db. To upload the data. For exapmle, i need to connect the statistic for each oher user. When antoher user will log in, statistic will be upload from db